# What is wrong with this way of sending a multicast message of a packed struct?

Tags: c++, multicast

Is this incorrect?

```
ssize_t rc;
do
{
    rc = ::sendto(fd_, (char*) &fooStruct, sizeof(fooStruct), 0, &sockAddr_, sizeof(sockAddr_));
} while ((rc == -1 && errno == EINTR));

if (rc < 0)
    cout << "failed to mcast message " << endl;
```

It seems to keep failing and am wondering if I should be doing this instead:

```
ssize_t rc = ::sendto(fd_, (char*) &fooStruct, sizeof(fooStruct), 0, &sockAddr_, sizeof(sockAddr_));
if (rc < 0) 
    cout << "failed to mcast message " << endl;
```

Comment: What is the value of `errno`?  What do you see if you print out `strerror(errno)`?

Comment: @eile it is, it is 52 bytes i think. Why?

Comment: UDP messages are limited to 64k size, but this is nor your error. Knowing the errno would help.